# Clicking back from a Fragment in an Activity displays empty Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, fragment

I have an `Activity` with one `Fragment`.

If I select an item from Navigation Drawer, the `Fragment` is changed using `FragmentTransaction`. If I click the back button, it goes to the previous `Fragment`. When I click back again, the `Fragment` disappears and an empty `Activity` is displayed.

Why does this happen ? How do I overcome this ?

Comment: Also add code, no one can *figure out* what is wrong, with this information. We can only guess.

Answer (score 1):

Just Check If fragments in Your backstck or not, if not then show exist app dialog.

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

            int fragments = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
            if (fragments == 1) {
                finish();
            } else {
                if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
                    getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                } else {
                    super.onBackPressed();
                }
            }
    }
```